Scrolling on div does not work after applying transformation (Matrix3d)
The problem is that when you try to scroll the #content div, it does not work. Scrolling with the scrollbar works, however:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    .page {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: red;
      width: 90vw;
      height: 90vh;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    #content {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200vh;
      background-color: green;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 1440px; height: 820px; perspective: 989.827561px;">
<div style="transform-style: preserve-3d; width: 1440px; height: 820px; transform: translateZ(989.827561px) matrix3d(0.599134, 0.00687, 0.800619, 0, -0.004679, -0.999916, 0.012081, 0, -0.800635, 0.010985, 0.599052, 0, -33.888354, 168.546007, 72.503973, 1) translate(720px, 410px);">
<div class="page track0" style="transform: translate(-50%, -50%) matrix3d(0.032176, 0, -0.042115, 0, 0.000519, -0.052996, 0.000396, 0, 0.042112, 0.000653, 0.032173, 0, -94.514369, 166.635279, -114.904453, 1);"><div id="content"></div></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

I figured it has something to do with both the transformations (when you remove both, it works). I really have no idea why this is happening. The values of the transformation are arbitrary, but it should work for any values. The structure should not be changed, since this is just a snippet of what is created by a library I am using (three.js, CSS3DObject).

Applying a transformation like matrix3d can alter an element's coordinate system, which may disrupt the browser's ability to handle events like scrolling correctly. By separating the scrollable area from the transformed element, you preserve the natural flow and event handling for the scrollable content.


body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.transform-wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.scrollable-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Scrolling with Transformation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="transform-wrapper">
            <div class="scrollable-content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <!-- Repeat the content to make it scrollable -->
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



